# Matlab - Removing image background using normalization

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image like this:
[image]

[my goal is to get the output under **background normalization** at this link](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVDICT/cvb.htm). 
Following the above link, I did the following: 
[(1). I first dilate the image to get the background](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html) 
[(2). then try to remove it via normalization](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdivide.html)

I got the background:
[image]

However, when I try to do the normalized division, I get this : 
*(black borders added to make clear of the boundary of the image)*
[image]

this is my code:

```
image = imread('image.png');
image = rgb2gray(image);
se = offsetstrel('ball',9,9);
dilatedI = imdilate(image,se);
output = imdivide(image,dilatedI);
imshow(output,[]);
```

using

```
imshow(output)
```

just gives a black image.

I thought it might be a type conversion issue, but based on the resources mentioned earlier, I am uncertain if it is the case...

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make sure you dont do integer division! your images are integer type, so `4/5` returns `0` and `5/4` returns `1`, not a floating point number. Just convert to float before dividing:

```
image = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIVRT.png');
%image = rgb2gray(image); The image is not a RGB online
se = offsetstrel('ball',21,21);
dilatedI = imdilate(image,se);
output = imdivide(double(image),double(dilatedI));

figure
subplot(121)
imshow(image);
subplot(122)
imshow(output);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! Will take note of this in future!